# chfs does not work in a login ksh shell

Tags: ksh, aix

I can't find a reason why chfs command fails in ksh (I open ssh sesion with putty). But when I run ksh or ksh93 in the shell again then it works.

Any clues?

```
# alias|grep chfs
# type chfs
chfs is /usr/sbin/chfs
# /usr/sbin/chfs -a size=+256M /opt
Usage: chfs [-n nodename] [-m newmtpt] [-u mtgrp] [-A {yes|no}] [-t {yes|no}] [-p {ro|rw}] [-a attr1=val1] [-d attr] fsname
# ksh93
# /usr/sbin/chfs -a size=+256M /opt
Filesystem size changed to 4194304
# ksh
# /usr/sbin/chfs -a size=+256M /opt
Filesystem size changed to 4718592
# exit
# exit
# /usr/sbin/chfs -a size=+256M /opt
Usage: chfs [-n nodename] [-m newmtpt] [-u mtgrp] [-A {yes|no}] [-t {yes|no}] [-p {ro|rw}] [-a attr1=val1] [-d attr] fsname
# f root
Login name: root                      In real life: Super User
Directory: /root                        Shell: /usr/bin/ksh
On since Sep 06 05:56:55 on pts/4, 4 minutes 30 seconds Idle Time
    from qlhhubfc
On since Sep 06 06:59:40 on pts/6
    from xxxxxxxxxxxx
No Plan.
# ksh
# /usr/sbin/chfs -a size=+256M /opt
Filesystem size changed to 5242880
```

Comment: What oslevel is this?

Comment: In the shell where it's failing, could you run it again but first execute `set -x` so that the shell prints out exactly what is executed?

Comment: I can't reproduce this yet. It seems to me that you only get that specific Usage message if you don't provide the filesystem at the end, which you do appear to be providing. A mistaken filesystem (leading/trailing blank, not-a-forward-slash, etc) will be reported with a different error. Looking forward to the `set -x` output from the failing version.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the shell is interpreting one of the arguments, try

```
/usr/sbin/chfs '-a' 'size=+256M' '/opt'
```